# Spacing in commands for math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros

I would like to define commands with semantics similar to e.g. + in math mode. For instance,

```
$(x+y)$
```

produces an equation with some spacing around +, whereas

```
$(+)$
```

produces an equation with less (or no) spacing around +.

The reason is that I would like to write something like

```
$\token{repeat} \token{skip} \token{until} b$
$\token{skip}$
```

Where tokens are follwed by a space in the first case, but are not in the second. In a way, I'd like something similar to xspace, in math mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: + gets it space from being a `\mathbin` but `\mathbin{\hbox{#1}}` doesn't do what you want....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `mathop` spacing is what you are looking for.

[image]

```
\def\token#1{\mathop{\hbox{#1}}}

.$\token{repeat} \token{skip} \token{until} b$.


.$\token{skip}$.

\bye
```

`\DeclareMathOperator` in `amsmath` package for LaTeX.